# terraform unknown resource error configuring an autscaling group for multiple target groups

Tags: terraform

Question about a Terraform error I’m getting when I try to add a second Target group to an Autoscaling group.

I created  a new target group successfully called "ext_alb_targetgroup".  It shows up in the AWS console and an ALB listener is forwarding to it.  I want to add this new target group  to an existing ASG as a second target group for the ASG.  From the Terraform documentation an ASG can be a member of multiple target groups and the  argument “target_group_arns” can be passed a list of TGs.  So I added my new TG to the list in the ASG.  The ASG I'm configuring is in one module and the new TG I'm trying to add into this ASG configuration is in another module.  When I run a terraform plan it throws the following error:

```
Error: resource 'aws_autoscaling_group.asg' config: unknown resource 'aws_alb_target_group.ext_alb_targetgroup' referenced in variable aws_alb_target_group.ext_alb_targetgroup.arn
```

I ran ‘terraform show’ and it finds the TG resource just fine and like I said the TG resource is AWS.

Does anyone have any idea why terraform is throwing this error?  Am I not calling the resource properly?  This is the target_group_arns list  that I have in the ASG configuration:

```
target_group_arns         = [   "${aws_alb_target_group.alb_targetgroup443.arn}",
  "${aws_alb_target_group.ext_alb_targetgroup.arn}"
                            ]
```

The second TG is the one TF is throwing the error about.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using a version that the resource got changed

https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#110-october-16-2017

```
resource/aws_alb_* & data-source/aws_alb_*: In order to support network LBs, ALBs were renamed to aws_lb_* due to the way APIs "new" (non-Classic) load balancers are structured in AWS. All existing ALB functionality remains untouched and new resources work the same way. aws_alb_* resources are still in place as "aliases", but documentation will only mention aws_lb_*. aws_alb_* aliases will be removed in future major version. (#1806)
Deprecated:
    data-source/aws_alb
    data-source/aws_alb_listener
    data-source/aws_alb_target_group
    resource/aws_alb
    resource/aws_alb_listener
    resource/aws_alb_listener_rule
    resource/aws_alb_target_group
    resource/aws_alb_target_group_attachment
```